# Replace text on all tables of MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For a single table, following SQL query works fine to replace text:

```
UPDATE `TABLE_NAME` SET `COLUMN_NAME` = replace(COLUMN_NAME, 'Old_Text', 'New_Text')
```

I want to replace the keyword 'August' from the whole database to 'September'. Is there anything except manual find/replace on the `dump` for replacing the text from whole database? The `dump` would be of no help as database size is very huge.

Comment: every column in every table?

Comment: Do you mean there are lot of tables in the database that have a column named August ?

Comment: I mean, I have a huge database with multiple tables on it and multiple columns on those tables. There is no column named August but August appears as text / data on different columns. I want to change all 'August' on the database to 'September'.

Comment: you could use the information_schema tables to iterate through all tables and their columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Linux/Unix and are sure you don't have any fields/tables namned August, you could use `sed` to replace every text August with September:

```
sed -i 's/August/September/g' mydumpfile.sql
```