# Update data if matching value and column in all table

Tags: sql, database, select, toad, rdbms

I have a problem on updating value in a column named 'ST_CODE' exists in many tables throughout the database.

I am able to find out the table that contain the column "ST_CODE" with the following codes.

```
SELECT c.name As ColNames, t.name as TableNames 
FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE c.name='ST_CODE'
```

Is it possible to update the value from '00000' to '11000' for all the columns named 'ST_CODE' within all the tables?

Many thanks!

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803589/replace-text-on-all-tables-of-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. create a stored procedure and insert your tablename and column name in a temporary table.

```
  Insert into #temp(SELECT c.name As ColNames, t.name as TableNames 
  FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
  WHERE c.name='ST_CODE')
```

Then loop your temp table and write update statement as you needed. Please follow this link for assistance.  http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/24259/how-to-update-a-dynamic-sql-table-with-a-set-varia.html